# Trying to add a second view in a new component in Joomla! 3.x

Tags: php, joomla, components

I'm developing a component for Joomla! 3.x and I came across a strange issue. I followed the official documentation (http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions) and I was able to get somewhere. Now the problem is that I wanted to expand the tutorial and create submenus within the components menu in the backend. I succeeded with this too.

The 2 submenu selections link correctly to 2 different views and I am able to fetch data from different tables nicely. The problem is that I cant add new entry to the database using my second view. The first view works fine. On the second view, when I click the green Add button, I get a jquery error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of null

The problem is that the addNew method cant find municipality.add or something. However this (almost) same code works for the default view.

What I'm trying to do is to display the data of 2 different tables in the DB and then being able to edit delete or add new.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the problem was in the views/municipalitys/tmpl/default.php.

The form contained in that file was wrong, missing the id="adminForm" and the proper action= value.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
municipality.add
```

and

```
municipalitys.delete
```

refers to two different controllers, named `municipality.php` and `municipalitys.php`

You need to ensure the methods are present, in your case municipality.php should contain a

```
public function add()
```

which is not there.  For a reference on how to implement it look at the other controller (most likely you'll invoke the `add()` method of the relevant model).

Or possibly you're extending the `municipality` controller from a different ancestor that doesn't implement the `add` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I have to add these functions as tasks in the appropriate controllers but my question is why the default view works without that implimentation? This is the code of the controller of the first view. <?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
 
// import Joomla controllerform library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');
 
/**
 * HelloWorld Controller
 */
class TestControllerTest extends JControllerForm
{
}

And it works fine when calling lets say test.add

Comment: Your working controller extends JControllerForm which implements the add method, the other controller most likely does not.

Comment: Do I need to add any includes on the second controller to implement it? I'm here for about 2 hours trying everything and not succeeding with the second controller although they are identical.

Comment: At this point, why don't you implement the add() method and see if it gets invoked, the issue may be on other parts of the code preventing access to it, or to security issues (are the two controllers using the same privileges i.e. core.edit or do they have dedicated ones?)

Comment: I added the add() function but I still get the same error when clicking on the New button. Both the views and the controllers are used exactly as the example on the docs. I havent set any privileges to them and that might be the reason why the default works ( it has the same name as the component ) and the second one doesnt. Basically what I did is to copy paste the working controller/view/model/etc change name and DB tables and then invoke it with &view=secondview .

Comment: If you invoke the task directly, not from the button, does it invoke it? option=com_helloworld&task=municipality.add

Comment: Actually yes it does. Even the extended one works fine. I removed my add() function and the New form appeared correctly.

Comment: Use JToolbarHelper::custom instead of JToolbarHelper::addNew it may work (although I can't think of why it wouldn't work with addNew)

Comment: Using  JToolBarHelper::custom('municipality.add'); makes the button behave like an edit button and it asks me to select something from the list first. This is really strange. I think I have to register/include something somewhere. There is certainly something I'm missing.

Comment: JToolBarHelper::custom('municipality.add', 'add.png', 'add2.png', 'Add', false);  The last param specifies if there needs to be an item selected.

Comment: Thanks but the JS error is stil there and nothing happens when I click the button. Still I can access the New item form when typing the link and task directly.

Comment: I found the problem but I don't know how to fix it. Using Chrome Debugger I noticed this code: <input type="hidden" name="task" value="test.add"> on the working view and this code on the non working: <input type="hidden" name="task" value> Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You never mentioned a javascript error. No idea but test is a new controller? Were they not municipality/s?

Comment: The test is the default view/controller that works. Its just an example. The municipalitys is the view that doesnt work. For some reason the hidden input field doesnt get populated on the second view.

Comment: You have two names in the task, "municipality" and "municipalitys" then is this a typo?

Comment: Fixed it! The problem was in the views\municipalitys\tmpl\default.php.

The form wasnt setup correctly missing the id="adminForm" as well as the proper action="" value. Now everything works correctly. 

PS: No it wasnt a typo. Following the tutorial, I created both municipality and municipalitys. Its like the helloworld and helloworlds. I also checked the com_banners component and it works the same. "client and clients". Isn't it necessairy?

Comment: Yes it is, the plural for the list, the singular for creating / editing / viewing items

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time anyway Riccardo. :)

Comment: You're welcome!  Please improve your question and add yourself the right answer, this will help other users find it